# error: too many initializers for ‘const __class_type_info_pseudo’

Tags: g++

Did anyone ever see this compiler error before:

> error: too many initializers for
>   ‘const __class_type_info_pseudo’

Comment: I'm also seeing this error. I've been trying to produce a minimal example that exercises the problem with no luck. I've got a line that looks like this (with different variable names, of course):  foo->quux(BLAH, bar.get< Baz<Buffer> >("buffer_name"));  The error only occurs if the template argument to bar.get is itself templatized. For example, bar.get<int> works just fine. Weirder still, the error occurs on the last line of the .cc file for the object, regardless of whether the method containing this line is placed in the .cc or .h file. Really, really bizarre.

Comment: Here's a bit of stripped-down code that produces the same compile-time error: http://codepad.org/Ja0EN5TP

Comment: Reported upstream: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49387 Thanks for the test case !